# how to create a crystal Report with condition

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a table like this image.
[image]

I want to create report from that table with condition.
I want to sum if Purpose Column is Banana then sum LoanAmount. Example: On the table There are 2 records of Purpose= "Banana" So LoanAmount will be 120000 for Banana. I also want to sum LoanAmount if LoanStatus="UC" and so on. How can i create that report?

Comment: Write down (in text form), how should final report look - currently this is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: I want to Show in Total LoanAmount of Banana, Total LoanAmount of UC and Total LoanAmount of RecoveredBy Deb. Example: Here Purpose of Banana LoanAmount is 500000 and 70000. I want to show in report Total of Banana= 120000, And Total UC Amount=50000 and Total Recovered By Deb=220000.

Comment: I meant text, formatted like table, not verbal description or image :) And not in comments - you can edit original post. Currently I can't guess, how many rows and what columns you want to see (based on sample data). Can you create SQL views, BTW? Multiple unrelated groupings are usually simpler to perform on SQL level.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to simply insert a CrossTab in the report header or footer. Set rows to 'Purpose' and value to sum as 'Loan Amount'.

Another option is to create 3 formulas. The one for 'Banana' would look like:

```
IF {Purpose} = "Banana" Then {LoadAmount} ELSE 0
```

Then SUM those formulas to get the totals.

You can also use a Running Total with an evaluation condition but the approaches above are better.

Comment: I tried your formula but when I view the report it creates pages for every records. Example: if I have 5 records crystal report created 5 pages.

Comment: shared CurrencyVar Total;
IF ({tblRecovery.Purpose}) = "Banana" THEN
Total:= Total + {tblRecovery.Amount} else 0  I use this formula but it shows every records of the data table. Which is not banana it's show 0 and which is banana it shows its value. I want to get results total amount for banana in single text.